# Do push-fit braided stainless steel hoses with ball valve and MNPT adapter provide a swiveling connection?

Tags: plumbing, shutoff, adapter, pushfit

I don't have access to one of these hoses in person to be able to determine the answer for myself, and have only seen pictures of them online.  Does either the ball valve or the MNPT adapter spin freely of the hose, or is the entire assembly "fixed" in the sense that when the MNPT adapter turns, the ball valve turns along with it? I'm assuming the latter, but if so, you could end up with the shutoff valve handle awkwardly inaccessible, between the hose and the wall, if the hose runs parallel to the wall.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the mating nut provide repositioning ability?

Comment: The MNPT  thread would mate with a stationary manifold with FNPT threads for inflow and outflow.  It's a water-filtration system that would be hard to spin onto the MNPT thread, especially since the FNPT threads are terribly easy to cross-thread on these units.

Comment: And the manifold's FNPT threads are also extremely touchy. Even the slightest adjustment to the depth of the thread insertion can cause a slow dripping leak. It's almost like you can get them to start leaking by saying "Boo!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the ball valve and the fitting will turn on the hose, but they are tight.

Normally the assembly would be held and the female fitting tightened to the male . However the both ends will turn to avoid an awkward handle position.

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering using them on a multi-stage water filtration system where the filter canisters are part of a manifold unit with female inflow and outflow ports. Spinning the entire manifold around wouldn't be nearly as easy as keeping it stationary and threading the hose's MNPT threads into it.